# How to write a web service in PHP that allows me to tweet from the command line with a single GET/POST request? (Handles oAuth)

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to create a simple web service that can post tweets to a specific Twitter account.

Basically, I was using BasicAuth before, but now that oAuth is required I would like to create a custom script that accepts a POST request with BasicAuth, and then my service would take care of the oAuth and post the data to Twitter.

Any pointers? I don't even know where to start, but surely someone must've done this before... Thanks in advance!

TL;DR I want to be able to tweet from the command line just by doing a single GET/POST `curl` request to my custom web service, which then handles the oAuth connection to Twitter behind the scenes.

Comment: @ajreal: PHP-CLI? I just want a PHP web service, but `POST` to it from Unix using `curl` (not the PHP command line interface). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Kind of confused by your title, mind to edit again?